# How do you check if an array's values includes one or multiple values?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm looking to see if an array has one or more values inside it. For instance, something like so:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6].include?([4,1])  # => true
[4,1,6,2].include?([4,1])  # => true
[3,4,7].include?([4,1])  # => false
```

Of course, the "include?" method can only check one value. Is there a method to check for multiple values?

Comment: Which Ruby version have you used here?
I am getting false on every occasion.
irb(main):006:0> [1,2,3,4,5,6].include?([4,1])
=> false
irb(main):007:0> [4,1,6,2].include?([4,1])
=> false
irb(main):008:0> [3,4,7].include?([4,1])

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**EDIT:** I endorse [Mark Thomas'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893884/ruby-how-do-you-check-if-an-arrays-values-includes-one-or-multiple-values/4893999#4893999) alternate solution that uses the core `Set` [class](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Set.html).

While my solution more strictly answers the question at hand of how to do this with arrays, sjsc may benefit from reviewing his own case and exploring the option of using sets instead.

There are plenty of valid reasond to use arrays (maintaining order, allowing for duplicates), for which the below still suffices, but if none of these are involved, sjsc might actually benefit from using Set instead of Array, and to that extent, Mark's solution is semantically superior.

---

I don't know of any library method that does this, but it wouldn't be too hard to write your own function.

```
class Array
  def subset?(a)
    (self - a).length == 0
  end
end
```

I'm sure there are computationally more efficient ways to accomplish this, but this should do what you're looking for.

Doing array intersection works and basically amounts to the same thing.

```
class Array
  def subset?(a)
    (self & a).length == length
  end
end
```

Optimization at this level isn't going to help matters too much, but what you don't want to do is start comparing arrays multiple times:

```
class Array
  # don't do this
  def subset?(a)
    (self & a) == a
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome method. Thank you Steven!

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel, when the Set class is in the core library. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. It's my error I didn't do my research before answering the question to look for a "set" class.

Answer (score 61):

```
>> [1,2,3,4,5,6] & [4,1]
=> [1, 4]
>> [1,2,3,4,5,6] & [7,9]
=> []
>>
```

Comment: Great approach kurami. Thanks!

Comment: Just making a note that this means. Ampersand is the set-intersection operator, returning a collection of common elements in both arrays.

Comment: One pitfall to watch out for is that the orders may be transposed. In order to check that A is subset of B, use A & B == A; B & A == A won't always work if B and A are ordered differently.

Comment: To get the boolean result indicated by the OP, use `any?` like so `([1,2,3,4,5,6] & [4,1]).any? #=> true`

Answer (score 26):

This is a set operation. `Set` is in the standard library.

```
require 'set'

a = Set[1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = Set[4,1]

b.subset? a
#=> true
```

Comment: Worked great for me, Thank you.  Just wanted to mention that Set[1].proper_subset? Set[1] will return false. So if you can't guarantee you will be dealing with multiple values, Set[1].subset? Set[1] will return true, as well as the example above returning true.

Comment: note that this is pretty slow if you are converting an array to a set, compared to (a & b).size == b.size which seems to be the fastest

Comment: @mrbrdo While that is true, sometimes you really want a Set (e.g. with automatic deduplication) in which case an Array shouldn't have been constructed to begin with! In my opinion, the standard library classes get overlooked far too often.

Comment: I'm just saying that in this case performance is much worse when using set. Set only really pays off if you use it from the start,  but if you convert an array to a set this operation usually takes longer then the operation you actually want to perform, so it's not worth it in such cases. But yeah Set is great otherwise, I do sometimes use it. Just need to be aware of performance considerations.

Comment: Slower or not, when you need to make double-sure, this is the perfect method and this is what I would pick as the expected answer.

Answer (score 6):

A quick and dirty extension to @Schwartzie's approach:

```
larger_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
smaller_array = [4,1]
smaller_array.all? {|smaller_array_item| larger_array.include?(smaller_array_item)}
```

Answer (score 5):

Base on kurumi and spyle's suggestion, here are my test:

> > ([1,2,3,4,5,6] & [4,1]).any? #=> true

However, .any? will turn any objects to true

> > ([1,2,3,4,5,6] & [6,7]).any? #=> true

So I think here might be a working one:

> > ([1,2,3,4,5,6] & [6,7]).length == [6,7].length #=> false

( bigger_array & smaller_array ).length == smaller_array.length

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with `[1,2,3,4,5,6].include?(4) and [1,2,3,4,5,6].include?(1)`?

Comment: Thanks Schwartzie. Do you know if there's a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Really appreciate trying to help Schwartzie. Thank you again.

Comment: Thanks, Schwartzie! I don't know the internals of `-`, so it may not strictly be the best approach, and it's of mid- polynomial average and worst case complexity, so that makes me a bit concerned. If we wanted to go uglier but more efficient, we'd just stop the checker as soon as you find one element `self` that's not in `a`. Then again, I don't know if the Ruby interpreter won't do this automagically.

Comment: @Schwartzie include? does not work if you do 
[1,2,3,4,5,6].include?([1,4])  which is what is required

Comment: @Ross, you're right about Array.include? taking only a single scalar argument, but what I proposed is getting the union of two Array.include? calls with the logical operator AND.

Answer (score 3):

I like kurumi's answer, but just to throw one more out there:

```
>> set1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
[
    [0] 1,
    [1] 2,
    [2] 3,
    [3] 4,
    [4] 5,
    [5] 6
]
>> set2 = [4,1]
[
    [0] 4,
    [1] 1
]
>> set1.any?{ |num| set2.include?(num) }
true
>> set2 = [8,9]
[
    [0] 8,
    [1] 9
]
>> set1.any?{ |num| set2.include?(num) }
false
```

Answer (score 2):

My conclusion is that the *Subtraction* method is generally nice, but actual **Set** objects are blazing fast since they are clearly optimized for this type of computation.

Using this script: https://gist.github.com/1996001

I got these benchmark results (on Ruby 1.9.2p290):

```
SUBTRACTION
- subset
  0.180000   0.000000   0.180000 (  0.189767)
- partial subset
  0.170000   0.000000   0.170000 (  0.178700)
- non subset
  0.180000   0.000000   0.180000 (  0.177606)

INTERSECTION
- subset
  0.190000   0.000000   0.190000 (  0.194149)
- partial subset
  0.190000   0.000000   0.190000 (  0.191253)
- non subset
  0.190000   0.000000   0.190000 (  0.195798)

SET
- subset
  0.050000   0.000000   0.050000 (  0.048634)
- partial subset
  0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.045927)
- non subset
  0.050000   0.010000   0.060000 (  0.052925)
```

Which I consider pretty startling, especially if you check out the source:

```
# File 'lib/set.rb', line 204

def subset?(set)
  set.is_a?(Set) or raise ArgumentError, "value must be a set"
  return false if set.size < size
  all? { |o| set.include?(o) }
end
```

via: http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/set/1.9.2/Set#subset%3F-instance_method

Comment: yes but conversion from array to set is not very fast, usually you'd have to take that into account

Comment: Perhaps. And while I don't convert the Array into a Set for each iteration, I do convert it once for each Set test, so its completely dwarfed by the speed of the Set operations at that level. If you're going to be doing such a large number of Set operations, then you should do the same, convert to Set once (or start with a Set) and then do your repetitious operations, rather than constantly converting back and forth between Set and Array.

Answer (score 2):

Simple and best way :

([4,1] - [1,2,3,4,5,6]).empty?  # => true

([4,1] - [4,1,6,2]).empty? # => true

([4,1] - [3,4,7]).empty? # => false

Answer (score 1):

@kurumi has it right but I thought I'd add that I sometimes use this little extension when I only want a subset of an array (usually the hash keys though):

```
class Hash
  # Usage { :a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3}.except(:a) -> { :b => 2, :c => 3}
  def except(*keys)
    self.reject { |k,v|
      keys.include? k
    }
  end

  # Usage { :a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3}.only(:a) -> {:a => 1}
  def only(*keys)
    self.dup.reject { |k,v|
      !keys.include? k
    }
  end
end

class Array
  def except(*values)
    self.reject { |v|
      values.include? v
    }
  end

  def only(*values)
    self.reject { |v|
      !values.include? v
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: This is going to be extremely useful. Really appreciate you typing that all out! Thank you so much scragz.

Comment: Array.except exists in standard ruby as -  
Array.only exists in standard ruby as &  
See: [1,2,3] - [1,3] => [3] and [1,2,3] & [1,2] => [1,2]

Answer (score 0):

This will check whether an element exists in a array:

```
students = ["jim", "bob", "sally"]
teachers = ["mrs. jones", "mrs. sharpe", "mrs. ray"]

puts "what's your name ?"
answer = gets.chomp

if answer.include?(students.to_s)
  puts "you are a student"

elsif
  puts "you are a teacher"

end
```

Answer (score 0):

For checking array values contain single or multiple element you can convert array on "set" then can use "subset?" method like below.

```
    require "set"
    a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    b = [3,6]
    b.to_set.subset?a.to_set //true
    b= [3,7]
    b.to_set.subset?a.to_set //false
```